# Declare and get static variable in JSP

Tags: jsp, el

Is there any way in JSP to declare static variable apart from `<%! int like=0;%>`? Is there any tag in custom tags to declare static variable on JSP pages?

If not and if I declare my static integer variable 'like' this way `<%! int like=0;%>`, is there any way I get this variable value using EL like `${like}`? I want this value in my `JQuery` function, and I know I can get this value using `<%=like>`, but I need other way.

Comment: This doesn't declare a variable (there is no type), and it doesn't make the variable static. Static variables in general should be avoided. Scriptlets should also be avoided. And jQuery runs at client side, whereas JSPs are executed at server-side. What are you actually trying to do, at a higher level?

Comment: See I want one button or link on my JSP page. And the starting value starts from 0. And whenever user click on the button or link, this value gonna be incremented by 1.. I don't want to make AJAX call to save this value on Database.. I want this value on page only for all users..

Comment: If you want the value to be shared by all the users, you **need** to send a request to the server. Otherwise, it'll stay on each client's browser.

Answer (score 3):

Not static, but you can declare an application scoped variable using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/set.html).

```
<c:set var="like" value="0" scope="application" />
```

You can get it in your JS/jQuery code by simply letting JSP print it as if it's a JS variable.

```
<script>
    var like = ${like};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want do declare a variable on server-side which can be used on the client (browser), you can declare a Servlet Context Parameter in your web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>yourParamName</param-name>
    <param-value>yourParamValue</param-value>
  </context-param>
  ...
</web-app>
```

Expression language has an implicit object `initParam` where you can access Servlet Context Parameters on your JSP:

```
${initParam.yourParamName}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a JSP use `${staticVar.ClassName_staticPropertyName}` 
During context initialization do:

```
servletContext.setAttribute("staticVar", new AbstractMap&lt;String,Object>() {
    @Override
    public Set&lt;Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    @Override
    public String get(Object key) {
        return methodToGetStaticVariableUsingReflection(key)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's is not possible to access static variables using EL. You can't get value using EL if you are declaring static variable as

```
<%!
        public static int a=343;        
       %>
```

So you have to declare a variable as `<c:set var="a" value="${'hello'}" ></c:set>` using *EL*, then only you will get value (`<c:out value="${a}"></c:out>`) using *EL*.

You need to declare it as an instance variable, because there is only one copy of the jsp page (servlet) exists and the _jspService method invokes for each request so the same instance variable is available for all users (_jspService method). That means, no new instance of a servlet is created for each request.  Refer about [jsp life cycle](http://javapapers.com/jsp/jsp-life-cycle-explain/).

Comment: But I want a same variable for all user who can access the page. And whenever they click on button or link which I linked with this variable using JQuery is going to increase by 1.